# server side code not executing after returning true on jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to upload files using the Upload File Control from Asp.net.

Now i wired the button click on jquery and i will return true if it passes the validation.

here is the jquery code:

```
$("#Button1").click(function () {
  var empty = checkempty();
  if (!empty) {
    var accepttype = determintype();
    if (accepttype) {
      var acceptsize = determinesize();
      if (acceptsize) {
        alert('im here');
        return true;
      } else {
        $.ambiance({
          message: "File is too big check your mugshot size the size should not exceed 100kb!",
          title: "File type Restriction!",
          type: "error",
          timeout: 10,
          fade: true
        });
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      $.ambiance({
        message: "File type is restricted to JPEG!",
        title: "File type Restriction!",
        type: "error",
        timeout: 10,
        fade: true
      });
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    $.ambiance({
      message: "Please choose the mugshots to upload!",
      title: "Empty Queue!",
      type: "error",
      timeout: 10,
      fade: true
    });

    return false;
  }
});
```

at the condition where i test acceptsize variable that is where i am trying to return true to execute the server side code where it will be save to a folder inside my development machine.

I have tried setting the `ClientIDMode="Static"` but still no luck

The Alert i am here is showing and i am returning true but the server side code is not executing

am i lacking something?

thank you

here is the html part

---

```
    <div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Whole Body</label>
       <div class="controls">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="whole" runat="server" />
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Front</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="front" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Left Face</label>
       <div class="controls">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="left" runat="server" />
       </div>
    </div>
   <div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Right Face</label>
       <div class="controls">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="right" runat="server" />
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-actions">                                                                              
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btn-primary btn-large" runat="server"           Text="Start Upload" />
   </div>
```

Comment: Is your click event executing?

Comment: unfortunately no on server side

Comment: Are you sure it is returning true?  Put an alert inside if condition and confirm it.

Comment: yes i tried it already

Comment: Include your HTML/aspx portion also, couldn't find any specific issue in your javascript given.